# Compute fractional weights based on double-counting strings in R

Tags: r

I want to assign equal weights to my observations based on the number of  observations in the same group (ID), i.e. frac_weight = 1/count(same ID)

```
ID          frac_weight
FSGBR070N3  0.333333333
FSGBR070N3  0.333333333
FSGBR070N3  0.333333333
FS00008L4G  1
FS00008VLD  0.333333333
FS00008VLD  0.333333333
FS00008VLD  0.333333333
FS00009SQX  0.5
FS00009SQX  0.5
FSUSA0A1KW  0.5
FSUSA0A1KW  0.5
FSUSA0A1KX  1
FSUSA0A1KY  1
FS0000B389  0.5
FS0000B389  0.5
FSUSA09AX9  1
```

This is probably a one-liner, but I could only find more complex posts in this forum. I have started with:

```
ID_vec <- dat$ID
```

which singles out the ID column from my data.frame

Thanks, 
Wilhelm Fantastisch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try function `ave`.

```
ID_vec <- dat$ID

frac_w <- as.numeric(ave(ID_vec, ID_vec, FUN = function(x) 1/length(x)))
all.equal(dat$frac_weight, frac_w)
[1] TRUE
```

**Important Note:** If `class(dat$ID)` returns `factor` you will have to do

```
ID_vec <- as.character(dat$ID)
```

Answer (score 0):

The application seems perfect for using `table` in some way.

It uses one more line than Rui Barradas answer though:

```
inds <- sapply(df$ID, function(x){which(names(table(df$ID)) == x)})

1/(table(df$ID)[inds])
# FSGBR070N3 FSGBR070N3 FSGBR070N3 FS00008L4G FS00008VLD FS00008VLD FS00008VLD 
# 0.3333333  0.3333333  0.3333333  1.0000000  0.3333333  0.3333333  0.3333333 
# FS00009SQX FS00009SQX FSUSA0A1KW FSUSA0A1KW FSUSA0A1KX FSUSA0A1KY FS0000B389 
# 0.5000000  0.5000000  0.5000000  0.5000000  1.0000000  1.0000000  0.5000000 
# FS0000B389 FSUSA09AX9 
# 0.5000000  1.0000000
```

Comment: Thank you guys, this worked eventually        FundID_vec <- as.character(dat$FundID)

frac_weight <- as.numeric(ave(FundID_vec,FundID_vec,FUN=function(x) 1/length(x)))